# 301 redirect chain in html

Tags: redirect, http-redirect

I have searched on the internet and on your forum but just cannot find the code to write a chain redirect.
I understand that it is not good practice to redirect more than 3 times but I need to redirect two pages in my website both which have already been redirected once before.

My website is in HTML and I did the previous redirects on the .htaccess file.

I would like to redirect a second time but cannot find how to write this, would it be:

```
RedirectPermanent /old-page.html http://www.website/folder/new-page.html http://www.website/folder/new-page-two.html
```

**OR**

```
RedirectPermanent /old-page.html http://www.website/folder/new-page.html /folder/new-page-two.html
```

or do I redirect directly from the original redirected page? 
The first redirect was done about three years ago.

I also need to tell Google that some of my webpages do not exist anymore.  Can I put a 410 coding on the same .htaccess page or do I need a separate one or do I just delete them and tell Google through my Sitemap.xml?

I would be so grateful for your help with these confusing questions.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that it is not good practice to redirect more than 3
>   times but I need to redirect two pages in my website both which have
>   already been redirected once before.

It’s not a “bad practice” issue as you are describing. If a user visits `/old-page.html` how exactly are they going to go to two URLs from that? Is there any site on the Internet you have ever seen that?

I am assuming you want to have two different redirects. Which you can do like this:

```
RedirectPermanent /old-page.html http://www.website/folder/new-page.html
```

And then on `www.website` you do this:

```
RedirectPermanent /folder/new-page.html /folder/new-page-two.html
```

> I also need to tell Google that some of my webpages do not exist
>   anymore.

So if you have a page that doesn’t exist, it should return a 404 & Google will know that.  So what is the issue? Unless you want to force requests to 404. Then you would do something like this for a page like `bad-page.html` to 404 on each request:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^/?bad-page\.html$ - [R=404]
```

But it seems like you have very simple issues that you are overcomplicating.